# User Control's child controls not getting instantiated

Tags: asp.net

```
         public partial class ChatUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
        {
            UserChatClass ucc = new UserChatClass();
            public ChatUserControl()
            {
                lblChatFriend = new Label();
                txtChatMessage = new TextBox();
                imgFriend = new Image();
                rpChatMessages = new Repeater();
            }
            public string ChatFriend { get { return this.lblChatFriend.Text; } set { this.lblChatFriend.Text = value; } }
            public string imgFriendUrl { get { return this.imgFriend.ImageUrl; } set { this.imgFriend.ImageUrl = value; } }
            public object rpChatDataSource { get { return this.rpChatMessages.DataSource; } set { this.rpChatMessages.DataSource = value; } }
            public Repeater rpChatMessagesToBind { get { return this.rpChatMessages; } set { this.rpChatMessages = value; } }
            }


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
                { 
                    if (!IsPostBack) 
                    { 
ChatUserControl user1 = new ChatUserControl();
                    divChatUserControlCover.Controls.Add(user1);
                    } 
                } 
         private void BindUserControls()
                {                ChatUserControl user1 = divChatUserControlCover.Controls[1] as ChatUserControl;
                        user1.ChatFriend = row["username"].ToString();                    
                        user1.imgFriendUrl = "../../HttpImageHandler.jpg?username=" + row["username"].ToString(); 

                        DataSet dsCM = ucc.GetChatMessages(Session["username"].ToString(), row["username"].ToString());
                        user1.rpChatDataSource = dsCM;
                        user1.DataBindForRpChatMessagesToBind();
                        user1.Visible = true;

         }

    Master.aspx

    <div id="divChatUserControlCover" runat="server">

            </div>
```

Ok I have edited the code and now I have created properties. How do I call the DataBind method for rpChatMessages? I also cant see my usercontrol on page. Why

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your trying to reference the first label or second label. If its the second lable you can't just do `chatMessage.` you would have to do

```
((Label)rpChatMessages.FindControl("chatMessage")) due to scope of controls.
```

When you reference a component inside another component (ie `Repeater`) the child component no longer belongs to the document (implied `this`) but rather belongs to the control, ie

`this.rpChatMessages { chatMessage }`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just trying to pass a **value** to one control inside a `UserControl` if this is correct, declare a public property like this:

#### ASCX code behind

```
public string MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        return this.lbl.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        this.lbl.Text = value;
    }
}
```

#### Setting the value to the UserControl

```
private void BindUserControls() 
            { 
ChatUserControl user1 = divChatUserControlCover.Controls[1] as ChatUserControl; 
                    user1.MyProperty = row["username"].ToString();
```

#### Setting the value in the page markup

```
<uc1:ChatUserControl MyProperty='<%# Eval("some field") %>' ...
```

### Edit 1

Remove that line

```
public object rpChatDataSource { get { return this.rpChatMessages.DataSource; } set { this.rpChatMessages.DataSource = value; }
```

And instead add a **method**

```
public void BindMyRepeaterOrWhatever(IEnumerable<Yourentity> data)
{
    this.myDataBoundControl.DataSource = data;
    this.myDataBoundControl.DataBind();
}
```

You can change the `IEnumerable<Yourentity> data` for `object data` but if you can pass a strongly typed enumeration would be better

Comment: How do I call a property repeater.DataBind for a property public Repeater rpChatMessagesToBind { get { return this.rpChatMessages; } set { this.rpChatMessages = value; } }  
Should I do it like this....public void DataBindForRpChatMessagesToBind()
        {
            this.rpChatMessagesToBind.DataBind();
        }

Comment: I have edited the content and I dont see my updated usercontrol on my page. What am I doing wrong

Comment: Probably because you don't call `BindUserControls`

Comment: I am calling it in my master.cs page. Can we start a chat for this?

Answer (score 0):

To my surprise I found why my user control's child controls dont get instantiated. Its because `ChatUserControl user1 = new ChatUserControl()` doesnt get its child controls initialized. 
The proper way to create a new intance of user control is this way....

```
ChatUserControl user1 = (ChatUserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/ChatUserControl.ascx");
```